# how to backtracking in javascript?

Tags: javascript, backtracking

i write code that combinating all possibe words.
and here is code.

```js
const fs = require('fs');
const MAX = 9
var arr = new Array(MAX).fill(0);
var visited = new Array(MAX).fill(0);
word = []
N = 0
M = 0
fn = 0

function test(cnt, k, pos, ltr) {
  console.log("6.", cnt, k, pos, ltr)
  tmp = [];
  if (cnt == M) {
    for (i = 0; i < M; i++) {
      tmp.push(k[arr[i] - 1]);
      //console.log("1.",tmp);
    }
    j = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < fn; i++) {
      //console.log("1-1.",pos[i],ltr[j])
      tmp.splice(pos[i] - 1, 0, ltr[j]);
      //console.log("2",tmp);
      j += 1;
    }
    s = tmp.join("");
    //console.log("3",s);
    word.push(s);
    //console.log("4.",word);
    return;
  }
  for (i = 1; i <= N; i++) {
    if (visited[i] == 0) {
      visited[i] = 1;
      arr[cnt] = i;
      test(cnt + 1, k, pos, ltr);
      visited[i] = 0;
      console.log("5.", visited, arr);
    }
  }
}
k = process.argv[2];
M = Number(process.argv[3]);
N = k.length;
fn = Number(process.argv[4]);
X = N + M;
pos = [];
ltr = [];
console.log(k, M, fn, N);
for (i = 0; i < fn; i++) {
  pos[i] = process.argv[5 + 2 * i];
  ltr[i] = process.argv[6 + 2 * i];
}
//console.log(pos);
//console.log(ltr);
test(0, k, pos, ltr)
for (i of word) {
  console.log(i);
}
```

this code algorithm is worked different language like python,c++,but not javascript.
for example, i give a argument "visage 2 1 3 n",
other langaues prints "agn ain asn avn ean ..." but in this code only prints "vin vsn van ven"
i don't know where is the problem and how to fix it. so help me.
+) also inclde c++ code

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <algorithm>
/*
#ifdef _WIN32
#include <windows.h>
#endif
*/
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;
const int MAX = 8 + 1;
int fn;
int N, M, X;
int arr[MAX];
bool visited[MAX];
vector<string> word;
string cmd = "node checktest.js";
ofstream file("./input.txt");
void func(int cnt, string k, int pos[], char ltr[])
{
    cout<<cnt<<" "<<k<<"\n";
    vector<char> tmp;
    if (cnt == M)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < M; i++)
            tmp.push_back(k[arr[i] - 1]);
        int j = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < fn; i++)
        {
            tmp.insert(tmp.begin() + pos[i] - 1, ltr[j]);
            j++;
        }
        string s(tmp.begin(), tmp.end());
        word.push_back(s);
        return;
    }

    for (int i = 1; i <= N; i++)
        if (!visited[i])
        {
            visited[i] = true;
            arr[cnt] = i;
            func(cnt + 1, k, pos, ltr);
            visited[i] = false;
        }
}

int main(int args,char * argv[])
{
    /*
#ifdef _WIN32
    SetConsoleOutputCP(CP_UTF8);
#endif*/
    string k(argv[1]);
    N = k.length();
    M=atoi(argv[2]);
    fn=atoi(argv[3]);
    X = N + M;
    int *pos = new int(fn);
    char *ltr = new char(fn);
    for (int i = 0; i < fn; i++)
    {
        pos[i]=atoi(argv[4+2*i]);
        ltr[i]=argv[5+2*i][0];
    }
    func(0, k, pos, ltr);
    sort(word.begin(), word.end());
    word.erase(unique(word.begin(), word.end()), word.end());
    for (auto i : word)
    {
        file<<i<<"\n";
    }
    file.close();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to also include the original python code

Comment: I don't understand how you get the output from the input.